# Multiple row calculation with one fixed value

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-docs

I have a calculation like this

```
=B8+((B2-1)*C8)
```

I want to multiple these calculation by just dragging it down. So I don't need to type the calculation for each row. The values `B8` and `C8` shall increase to `B9` / `C9`, `B10` / `C10` and so on. But I want to be `B2` fixed (shall not increase).

Why?
`B2` is just a variable in this calculation. So it's not okay to hard code this value into the calculation.

Is this possible? And yes: how?

I tagged this with [google-docs](/questions/tagged/google-docs) and [microsoft-excel](/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) since I don't care too much about which tool I'll use. But I'll prefer an answer for google docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place dollar signs like this:  $B$2

Dollar signs are used for absolute references.  They allow you to copy the rest of the formula down without changing that cell.

You can also do:  $B1 or B$2

These will make it so the column or row will not change, respectively

Comment: BTW. the F4 key is a shortcut to placing these dollar signs on a cell identifier.  Just click into your formula where you want to put your absolute reference ( B2 in your case ) and hit the F4 key to toggle the absolute reference.

Comment: F4 is valid for Excel, LibreOffice uses SHIFT+F4 for the same thing.